# Why doesn't my state change when the category on useParams changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
 const { category } = useParams();
 const [sort, setSort] = useState(category);
```

This think is really driving me crazy - when i console the category, it is actually changing, but sort state doesn't..

Comment: need to use useEffect to update the state when params changed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some reading in order to understand how React Hooks work. There are many tutorials online - the React API documentation is even a good start:

> **What do we pass to useState as an argument?** The only argument to the useState() Hook is the initial state.

[From the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). Notice they say the argument is the *initial state* only.

When you do `useState(X)` - the value `X` is only used the *first time* the component is rendered. On subsequent renders, if and when `X` changes, and you want to use the new `X`, you must update the state value yourself via the `set` function returned by `useState`.

In your case, we can say that the state variable changes whenever `category` changes, so `category` is a dependency of the state variable. When you have a dependency of this kind, you know you need to use an *effect*, by way of the [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
const { category } = useParams();

const [sort, setSort] = useState(category);

// This callback will run whenever the dependencies
// specified in the second argument change.
useEffect(() => {
  setSort(category)
}, [category]) // <= the dependencies
```

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting whenever `category` changes, `sort` should also changes, if this is the goal, try this:

```
useEffect(() => setSort(category), [category]);
```

if you only want to change `sort` first time on initial render, try this:

```
useEffect(() => setSort(category), []);
```

For more info, see [Using the Effect Hook - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)